# getting parent object without passing its reference

Tags: java, inheritance

Is there a way to get the parent object which is aaaa in this case without passing it explictly to B?

```
class A {
    B b = new B();
}

class B {
    public void getParent(){
}

A aaaa = new A();
```

Comment: What is a parent object? The object which holds a reference to `B`? And what if several objects keep references to a `B`?

Comment: No. There's no "parent"; objects don't automatically know where they've been instantiated. Objects in a list don't have access to the list, for example, unless given a reference.

Comment: An object reference withinn B was created. Is there a way to do this? Sorry for the formatting, i thought it wont let me post that.

Answer (score 2):

you can pass aaaa as a argumet to the constructor of B

```
class A {
    B b = new B(this);
}

A aaaa = new A();

class B {
    private A parent;
    public B(A parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the object which has created the current instance (and not the one which holds a reference to, because there may be many objects referencing this object), you can navigate the call-stack to find the instantiating object in the constructor.